# Charge a battery with a capacitor

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, batteries

Though the opposite is readily found, battery charging a capacitor, I am looking to scavenge small generation capacities to charge a battery.  Things like piezoelectric effects or collecting electrostatic effects like https://youtu.be/fhj2BN-cbvg.  Such small charges need to be collected to be useful and my thought was to use a capacitor which if sufficiently charged could then dump to a battery.  My field is biology but I also teach general science so am wondering what circuit could be used to accomplish this?

Comment: a 1.5 V AA alkaline battery stores about 3.9 watt hours, or about 14,000 Joules. A 1 Farad capacitor (which is a VERY large capacitor) charged to 10 Volts stores only 50 Joules of energy.

Comment: The keyword is "energy harvesting". You can probably find many examples